# Adaptable by ag-grid height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [adaptable grid](https://docs.adaptabletools.com/reference) in my react project

My DOM structure looks like---

```
<TopHeader />
<AdaptableGrid />
<BottomHeader />
```

I just want to fix Top header and bottom header on the screen and I want to rest of the space to be taken by adaptable grid with scroller.

What is happening by default is that my bottom header is out of the page. I need to change the height of grid, but I want it to be reponsive as well.